# How to correctly use std::reference_wrappers

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, std

I am trying to understand `std::reference_wrapper`.

The following code shows that the reference wrapper does not behave exactly like a reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers = {1, 3, 0, -8, 5, 3, 1};

    auto referenceWrapper = std::ref(numbers);
    std::vector<int>& reference = numbers;

    std::cout << reference[3]              << std::endl;
    std::cout << referenceWrapper.get()[3] << std::endl; 
              // I need to use get ^
              // otherwise does not compile.
    return 0;
}
```

If I understand it correctly, the implicit conversion does not apply to calling member functions. Is this an inherent limitation? Do I need to use the `std::reference_wrapper::get` so often?

Another case is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    int b = 4;
    auto refa = std::ref(a);
    auto refb = std::ref(b);
    if (refa < refb)
        std::cout << "success" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This works fine, but when I add this above the `main` definition:

```
template <typename T>
bool operator < (T left, T right)
{
    return left.someMember();
}
```

The compiler tries to instantiate the template and forgets about implicit conversion and the built in operator.

Is this behavior inherent or am I misunderstanding something crucial about the  `std::reference_wrapper`?

Comment: `std::reference_wrapper` has some very specific uses for library-authors, being relevant to perfect forwarding and storing arguments (see e.g. `std::bind` and `std::thread`). I don't recommend using it outside of those situations.

Comment: `reference_wrapper` is not a replacement for references.

Comment: `template <typename T>
bool operator < (T left, T right)
{
    return left.someMember();
}` is an example of what to NEVER EVER EVER EVER DO when overloading an operator.  Any problems that result due to that code are not the problem of anything else in your code base. (ok, maybe in some ridiculously restricted and controlled `namespace` to be found via ADL, or similar other contrived situations)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Class `std::reference_wrapper<T>` implements an implicit converting operator to `T&`:

```
operator T& () const noexcept;
```

and a more explicit getter:

```
T& get() const noexcept;
```

The implicit operator is called when a `T` (or `T&`) is required. For instance

```
void f(some_type x);
// ...
std::reference_wrapper<some_type> x;
some_type y = x; // the implicit operator is called
f(x);            // the implicit operator is called and the result goes to f.
```

However, sometimes a `T` is not necessarily expected and, in this case, you must use `get`. This happens, mostly, in automatic type deduction contexts. For instance,

```
template <typename U>
g(U x);
// ...
std::reference_wrapper<some_type> x;
auto y = x; // the type of y is std::reference_wrapper<some_type>
g(x);       // U = std::reference_wrapper<some_type>
```

To get `some_type` instead of `std::reference_wrapper<some_type>` above you should do

```
auto y = x.get(); // the type of y is some_type
g(x.get());       // U = some_type
```

Alternativelly the last line above could be replaced by `g<some_type>(x);`.
However, for templatized operators (e.g. `ostream::operator <<()`) I believe you can't explicit the type.

Comment: "_This happens, mostly, in automatic type deduction contexts._" A main example of this to add would be when using range-`for` or `algorithm`s over containers of `reference_wrapper`s: using `auto` means we get the `wrapper`, which is usually not of interest, so we have to replace that with `for (ReferredType& foo)` and so on. So much for 'almost always `auto`', sadly. However, arguably that inconsistency is still preferable to storing raw pointers and having to use `*` and `->` everywhere in such loops, and presumably most would agree that using `reference_wrapper` conveys better semantics too.

Answer (score 2):

The call to `get` seems to be necessary because `std::reference_wrapper` does not conditionally implement `operator[]`. It does so for `operator()` (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/operator())). Confronted with a `std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<int>>` that uses `operator[]`, for some reason, C++ does not attempt conversions like the implicit conversion of `std::reference_wrapper` to a reference. I’m not entirely sure *why* this is the case. I checked Clang and GCC (latest versions: v16.0.0 and v13.0.0) and they both reject it for C++11 through C++20 as well as C++1b.