# Construct one list from element of another list without adding to heap memory

Tags: c++, stdlist

I am developing a memory critical application. I first generate a list, for example (C++11):

```
std::list<string> nodes({"Hello","Welcome", "Hi", "World"});
```

I need to now create a smaller list with the second and third elements of 'nodes.' Naively, I would do:

```
std::list<string> sub_nodes;
sub_nodes.push_back(*std::next(nodes.begin(),1));
sub_nodes.push_back(*std::next(nodes.begin(),2));
```

But this clearly allocates memory in the heap for `sub_nodes` by allocating new memory.

```
*(sub_nodes.begin()) = "NotWelcome"; //changing first element
std::list<string>::iterator it;
for(it=nodes.begin();it!=nodes.end();++it) cout<<*it<<'\t';
cout<<'\n';
//Hello Welcome Hi World
for(it=sub_nodes.begin();it!=sub_nodes.end();++it)
cout<<*it<<'\t';
cout<<'\n';
//NotWelcome Hi
```

What I wish to accomplish is to have the elements of `sub_nodes` occupy the same address of the elements of `nodes` from which they were created. In other words, I want the changes made to elements of `sub_nodes` reflected in those elements in `nodes` and vice versa. In C linked lists, this would be straight forward since the list nodes are basically pointers. How would I accomplish the same in C++?

Comment: also in c++ you can use pointers, though smart pointers are preferable

Comment: This is the question. How would I add elements to a std::list by reference?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but are you sure `std::list` is the best container for you? What are you using it for? What are the requirement that leads you to use a list over the default container `std::vector`? And if memory is critical, note that a `std::list` of X nodes uses *more* memory than a `std::vector` of X elements (because of the private node structures themselves). Perhaps you should use a `std::deque` instead (to get a little of both lists and vectors)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude because there is a possibility of data insertion, in my application.

Comment: You want to splice the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper), which works as a reference and is able to be stored in a container.

```
std::list<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>> sub_nodes; // #include <functional>
```

Note although `std::reference_wrapper` has an implicit conversion operator to its value type, [sometimes you still have to use its explicit `get` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18128298/5376789). For example, you have to use

```
(*sub_nodes.begin()).get() = "NotWelcome";
```

to change the referenced object.

The following is a full working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <list>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::list<std::string> nodes({"Hello","Welcome", "Hi", "World"});
    std::list<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>> sub_nodes;
    sub_nodes.push_back(*std::next(nodes.begin(), 1));
    sub_nodes.push_back(*std::next(nodes.begin(), 2));
    (*sub_nodes.begin()).get() = "NotWelcome"; 
    for (auto it = nodes.begin(); it != nodes.end(); ++it) std::cout << *it << '\t';
    std::cout << '\n';
    // Hello NotWelcome Hi World
    for (auto it = sub_nodes.begin(); it != sub_nodes.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << (*it).get() << '\t';
    std::cout << '\n';
    // NotWelcome Hi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `std::list<T>` owns its elements. Thats one major motivation for using std containers. They manage the lifetime of their elements. If you want the container to not own its elements then don't make it store `T`s. There are several options. With `std::list` you have the advantage that `std::list`s iterators do not get invalidated that easily (eg `std::vector` may reallocate and copy all elements on each insert, not the case for `std::list`). Hence, you could use iterators:

```
std::list< std::list<std::string>::iterator > sub_nodes;
sub_nodes.push_back( nodes.begin() );
// etc..
```

Just be careful that if `nodes` invalidates its iterators, eg by erasing an element, then `sub_nodes` may contain invalid entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of string pointers.

```
std::list<std::string*> slist1;

slist1.push_back(new std::string("Hello"));
slist1.push_back(new std::string("Welcome"));
slist1.push_back(new std::string("Hi"));
slist1.push_back(new std::string("World"));
```

Then create another list using the same pointers.

```
auto it = slist1.begin();
std::list<std::string*> slist2(std::next(it, 1), std::next(it, 3));
```

This `slist2` list pointers are the same pointers as in `slist1`. Now changing any pointer will get reflected at both the places. For example, below code replace "Welcome" and "Hi" in slist2 with "abc". Changes are reflected in slist1 too as the pointers are same.

```
for (auto &s: slist2) {
        std::cout << *s << "\n";
       *s = "abc";
 }

for (auto &s: slist1) {
        std::cout << *s << " "; //prints Hello abc abc World
    }
```

Please note that this code is not exception safe and the list would have to be deleted manually. For exception safety and automatic destruction, please use smart pointers. Below is an example using shared_ptr.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <list>
int main()
{
    std::list<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> slist1;

    slist1.push_back(std::make_shared<std::string>("Hello"));
    slist1.push_back(std::make_shared<std::string>("Welcome"));
    slist1.push_back(std::make_shared<std::string>("Hi"));
    slist1.push_back(std::make_shared<std::string>("World"));

    auto it = slist1.begin();
    std::list<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> slist2(std::next(it, 1), std::next(it, 3));
    for (auto &s: slist2) {
        std::cout << *s << " ";
        *s = "abc";
    }

    for (auto &s: slist1)
        std::cout << *s << " ";  //prints Hello abc abc World
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would this approach work for other objects or structs other than std::string ?

Comment: Yes I think it should as we are using pointers(in this case it is string type but it can be other type too)

Comment: Please use smart pointers, otherwise the code is not exception safe and you have to manually delete those strings before the list is destructed. Also, `*s = "abc"` is enough for changing a string. `std::string` is mutable in C++.

Comment: You have undefined behaviour here. You are derefencing pointers that were invalidated by a previous `delete`. It *so happens* that your implementation used the same addresses for the string allocations that were just released.

Comment: @Caleth - i don't think it is undefined behaviour. Pointer is not being dereferenced after deletion. IMHO delete ptr; ptr = new something; is not undefined behaviour. *ptr would have been undefined, but after allocation ptr points to a valid memory.

Comment: @xskxzr - yes you are correct. For exception safety and automatic destruction of memory, smart pointers should be preferred.

Comment: Pointers in `slist1` are invalidated by the deletes looping through `slist2`

Comment: delete in `slist2` loop is deleting the content pointed to by the pointer and assigning new memory to it. It is not erasing the elements of the list or changing the list structure. AFAIK, this won't invalidate slist1. Please correct me if I am wrong.