# is it possible to create pointers of derived classes using their base class constructor without modifying the layout of the derived classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, unique-ptr

consider this layout:

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct data{};

struct task {
    data* data_ptr = nullptr;

    virtual void work() = 0;
};

struct special_task : task {

    void work() override { /*work with the data*/ }
};
```

a `task` has access to data. The derived classes must implement their indivial `work()` routine.

Now `task_collection` stores the data and a vector of task pointers, and instances of derived classes can be added to that vector:

```cpp
struct task_collection {
    data data;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<task>> tasks;

    template<typename T>
    void add() {
        this->tasks.push_back(std::make_unique<T>());
        this->tasks.back()->data_ptr = &this->data;
    }
};

int main() {
    task_collection t;
    t.add<special_task>();
}
```

now this works very well. However, I am wondering if I can replace the `data* data_ptr` with a reference as it seems more appropriate here and it also replaces the many `->` with `.`s

---

However, it seems impossible to implement this without changing the layout of `special_task` as the reference requires a constructor in the base `task` class and derived classes dismiss their base constructors:

```
struct task {
    task(data& data) : data_ref(data){}
    data& data_ref;

    virtual void work() = 0;
};

struct special_task : task {

    void work() override { /*work with the data*/ }
};

struct task_collection {
    data data;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<task>> tasks;

    template<typename T>
    void add() {
        this->tasks.push_back(std::make_unique<T>(this->data)); //Error!
    }
};
```

It gives this error:

```
Error   C2664   'special_task::special_task(const special_task &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'data' to 'const special_task &'
```

I am aware that this can be "solved" by adding

```
using task::task;
```

to every derived class, as now it now finds the appropriate constructor. This is not really a solution though, as there are hundreds of derived classes potentially, written by multiple people. If one instance of `using task::task;` is missing it could cause headaches. The additional lines of code also negate the benefit that comes from using reference instead of pointers.

---

So is there any way to implement `task::data_ref` as a reference where only `task_collection` or `task` are modified, but not any of the derived classes?

Comment: I don't think you can do what you're currently after without the using declaration. However, you could change your task concept a little. What about: work(data& data) instead of of work()? Then you don't need data as an instance variable at all, just pass data when you invoke the task.

Comment: Did you main problem is replacing `->` with `.` ? did you accept replace `->` with `.get().` or it is not acceptable for you?

Comment: @Wutz there is great benefit if each task can hold their own reference to the data, as there are more functions beyond `work()`. They are also passed to other functions where they are expected to work on their own without the extra `data` argument.

Comment: @StackDanny Did you see my question?

Comment: @sorosh_sabz a derived task can hold many variables and therefore there is a mixing between `.` and `->` which is not a huge problem in itself, but it would be nice if it was all uniform. And since the pointer shouldn't be changed beyond the construction, it's effectively a`data* const`, which is just exactly reference.

Comment: *If one instance of using task::task; is missing it could cause headaches.* Is a clear and simple compile-time error pointing out which class is missing the `using data::data;` really a headache?

Comment: @super the goal of this whole task is that it is very easy to use and understand by anyone, which is why I am debating the existence of the pointer in the first place. So yes, in this case it's against the motive and I would rather go back to the pointers than adding the using declaration. This is also true for `.get()` @sorosh_sabz

Comment: @StackDanny Ok my below answer can show a solution to using `.` in some case and using `.get()` in some another case for accessing `data`, but As you think, I think simpler solution is better than complicated solution, and in this question I prefer `->` for simplicity.

Comment: As @super pointed, I think `using data::data` is better than solution instead of using any complicated solution`. And it is not any meaningful headache in C++ world :D

Comment: @sorosh_sabz I agree with `->` for simplicity. I will go back to pointers for now. Maybe in the future someone finds a solution or a future standard provides one.

Answer (score 0):

If owner of question can accept some of time using `get()` instead of `.` to access to the data, he can use std::reference_wrapper instead of raw reference to resolve rebinding problem.

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

struct data{};

static data empty_data;

struct task {
    std::reference_wrapper<data> data_ptr = empty_data;

    virtual void work() = 0;
};

struct special_task : task {

    void work() override { /*work with the data*/ }
};

struct task_collection {
    data data;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<task>> tasks;

    template<typename T>
    void add() {
        this->tasks.push_back(std::make_unique<T>());
        this->tasks.back()->data_ptr = std::ref(this->data);
    }
};

int main()
{
    task_collection t;
    t.add<special_task>();
}
```

For using the data, you can for example behave like below

```
data temp_data = t.tasks.back()->data_ptr;
```

As you can see in [How to correctly use std::reference_wrappers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18128298/1539100), Class std::reference_wrapper implements an implicit converting operator to T&:

```cpp
constexpr operator T& () const noexcept;
```

So the implicit operator is called when a T (or T&) is required, and you do not need using `get()` function, For instance

```cpp
void f(some_type x);
// ...
std::reference_wrapper<some_type> x;
some_type y = x; // the implicit operator is called
f(x);            // the implicit operator is called and the result goes to f.
```

So you have to sometimes to using `.get().` instead of always using `->`

Comment: I guess it's a matter of taste, but i find .get() much worse than ->.